# Split string on un-escaped character in D

Tags: regex, string, split, d

What is the best way to split a string on an un-escaped character?
Eg. split this (raw) string

```
`example string\! it is!split in two parts`
```

on '!', so that it produces this array:

```
["example string! it is", "split in two parts"]
```

`std.regex.split` seems to almost be the right thing. There is a problem though, this code matches the correct split character, but also consumes the last character on the left part.

```
auto text = `example string\! it is!split in two parts`;
return text.split(regex(`[^\\]!`)).map!`a.replace("\\!", "!")`.array;
```

The whole regex match is removed on split, so this array is the result:

`["example string! it i", "split in two parts"]`

What is the best way to get to the first array without iterating the string myself?

Comment: which lang are you running?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind:

`(?<!\\)\!`